# Problem when exporting scored labels to excel

Tags: machine-learning, excel

I have done a regression using Azure ML Studio and it ok. The r squared is 95% on the test sample.
When predicting, the results look ok when visualizing the data.
The results appear as expected, with the predicted label having statistics very similar to the trained ones.[image]
But when I try to export it to Excel either: 
 1. consuming it from the web or 
 2. reading directly the saved dataset 
I obtain "weird" number like [image] instead of 41,36.[image]
How can I obtain right values?

Comment: Hi! I've noticed you are using the Spanish version of Excel. Have you double checked that your Excel uses dot (.) for decimals and not comma (,)? AZURE uses dot for decimals and Office products in Spanish use comma by default. Maybe this is causing the problem

Comment: Ok. It works as you say.

Comment:  Glad it finally helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by TitoOrt's comment the solution is simply changing the comma to the dot character as decimal point in Excel.

The reason was:

I am using the Spanish version of Excel. where is used the character dot (.) for decimals and not comma (,). AZURE uses dot for decimals and Office products in Spanish use comma by default.

Comment: This answer is accurate. Please consider accepting your own answer.

Comment: I edited the answer to make it clearer.